# SQL Server: bcp import from a xml file causes error

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I have a XML file dumped using `bcp`. Now I am trying to import it back, but it causes an error saying

> Unexpected end of file

My file looks like this:

```
<Records>
    <Record>
        <fileiid>6D6CB8B3-6FC0-E611-80CE-00155D04A60B</fileiid>
        <filesaveiid>2016121214342797001775113117639160154</filesaveiid>
        <datafilename>Howard Ray.png</datafilename>
        <datafilesize>0.03167057</datafilesize>
        <contenttype>.png</contenttype>
        <dataiid>2</dataiid>
        <createdon>2016/12/12 14:34:28</createdon>
        <createdby>mcarpenter</createdby>
        <modifiedon>2016/12/12 14:34:30</modifiedon>
        <modifiedby>mcarpenter</modifiedby>
        <annotation>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA.................</annotation> 
    <Record>
    ...
</Records>
```

Error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file

Command used:

```
exec xp_cmdShell 'bcp.exe [PREMIUM_DEMO_0]..[VG_Test] in d:\bcptest.xml  -c -T -x'
```

Do I really need to specify EOF to an XML based content?

Comment: Can you please post the bcp command you used to dump your data to xml file?

Comment: @Andrea sorry for late reply, here you go:

"exec xp_cmdShell 'bcp.exe \"select * from SomeTableName FOR XML PATH(''Record''), ROOT(''Records''), ELEMENTS XSINIL;\" QUERYOUT SomeTableXml.xml -S SQLServerName -T -w -r'";